# How to turn off syntax highlighting in Mobaxterm

Tags: mobaxterm

Mobaxterm always enables syntax highlighting, like this:

[image]

The ip and error message are colored, which I don't want.

I want to turn off syntax highlighting, but I cannot find the way. Setting default syntax highlighting to NONE is not working, and the official documentation is also blank for it.

Any suggestions on how to turn it off?

Comment: Just turn off this toy that is MobaXterm. Every company I've seen so far with poorly configured or poorly hardened servers had MobaXterm users. Treating servers like cattle? Yes please! Server hugging? Still acceptable. Abusing or being afraid servers because you rely on that one specific tool... super awkward. If your servers and applications don't present output to you in colors there may be a reason to find out, or you should learn to implement what you need. Tmux, vim, bash/readline, ansible, terraform. So much useful things I never heared or seen MobaXterm users make use of.

Answer (score 10):

Found out how.

Changing the settins at a global level is not enough. You also have to edit the session properties itself, under tab "terminal settings", at the bottom, there is a selection for 'Terminal colors scheme', set this to Default and set "Syntax highlighting"  to 'None'
The next time the session starts the coloured ip-numbers are gone!

Comment: I can't find `under tab "terminal settings", at the bottom, there is a selection for 'Terminal colors scheme', ` anywhere on my MobaXterm terminal. This is critical for me, as the default color scheme shows directories in dark green on a light green background, and is almost unreadable. I've set the default syntax highlighting to NONE, with no effect - as per the question. Still looking for the solution, but I'll have to abandon MobaXterm in the meantime. I'm using `WSL-OpenSuse` for the terminal.

Comment: @StephenHosking: as far as know mobaxterm does not colorize directories in the ls output. What you see is probably the feature of the `ls` command. Try `ls --color=no`

Answer (score 0):

Change it in the settings, then in your session, right click on anywhere on the screen, Select Syntax highlighting, and change to Default. I have to do this for each session though.